# SQLAlchemy logging with custom handler freezes

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy, handler

I am trying to write my own Python logging handler which would write log records into a database using SQLAlchemy, which would also be utilizing its own logging mechanism into the terminal (using echo=True).

This is the current simple + sample code:

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///logdb.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
class Log(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Log'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Log_message = Column(String)
    Timestamp = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, log_message=None, timestamp=None):
        self.Log_message = log_message
        self.Timestamp = timestamp

class DBHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        self.setFormatter(format)

    def emit(self, record):
        self.format(record)
        log = Log(
                log_message=record.__dict__['message'],
                timestamp=record.__dict__['asctime']
                )
        session = Session()
        session.add(log)
        session.commit()

def main():
    dbhandler = DBHandler()

    logging.getLogger().addHandler(dbhandler)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info('test_message')
```

However, the only log message I get into the terminal is the following:

```
2018-12-16 23:58:11,994 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
```

and the script gets stuck on the session.commit() line.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: On a quick glance, this looks like it has the makings of an infinite loop.

Comment: Seems like logging called by SQLAlchemy's own logging handler calls my own DBHandler, which in turns calls an SQLAlchemy's logging as it sends data into DB, but I am unable to figure out how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would be to use a separate engine that does not echo for logging (maybe).

Comment: Yeah that's what I got to right now, having DBHandler have its own engine, which works fine but the real database used is the same as the logging database - thus having multiple engines is probably not worth it, unless creating an engine in sqlalchemy is cheap. The ideal solution would be if it was possible to make certain calls as echo=False.

Comment: Use a dedicated logger instead of configuring the root logger and letting everything happen via propagation. In `main()`: `db_logr = logging.getLogger("test"); db_logr.addHandler(dbhandler); db_logr.setLevel(logging.DEBUG); db_logr.info('test_message')`.

Comment: Using another logger is a good solution, however, I would like to propagate all the logging via root - record other libraries' use of logging with the DBHandler as well. So far the one solution that's working seems to be using a separate engine that does not echo for the DBHandler.